# How can ı fix that if else problem Python?

Tags: python

It's works on "Not leap year" but it doesn't work on "Leap year":

```
month=int(input("Enter a month: "))
year=int(input("Enter a year: "))


if year%4==0 and year>=0:
    if year%100!=0:
        year="Leap Year"
        
    elif year%100==0:
        if year%400==0:
            year="Leap year"
        else:
            year="Not leap year"
    
elif year<0:
    print("Please enter a valid number")
    
elif year%4!=0 and year>0:
    year="Not leap year"
    
elif month<1 and month>12:
    print("Please enter a valid number")
    
if year=="Leap year":
    if month==2:
        print("Number of days:29")
    elif month==1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12:
        print("Number of days:31")
    else:
        print("Number of days:30")
    
if year=="Not leap year":
    if month==2 :
        print("Number of days:28")
    elif month==1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12:
        print("Number of days:31")
    else:
        print("Number of days:30")
```

In leap years ı think it's going in if state and cant go from if statement. How can ı fix that. However in not leap years it works because its get in elif statment.

Comment: Your “or”-expressions does not work as you think

Comment: Do not reuse the year variable as a string

Comment: ı have to year to str(year) ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
year="Leap Year"
```

`"Leap Year"` is not the same as `"Leap year"` because string comparison is case sensitive in python as well as in most programming languages.

In general it's not great practice to hardcode strings in multiple places. As other people have mentioned you don't probably don't want to reuse the `year` var in case you need it again. You should try using a new var and saving a boolean (`true` or `false`) value. Maybe name it `isLeapYear` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring `year="Leap Year"`, there are different spellings at different lines. At some point, it is "Leap Year" and at some point it is "Leap year". You need to be case sensitive in python. Try writing only "Leap year" everywhere and comparing `year=="Leap year"` in if statement